# asp.net mvc3 windows authentication only works on local computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have a mvc3 applicaiton using windows authentication. it works fine on my local pc.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

after I deploy it to the dev server.  every time, i go to the site, a login popup shows up, I need to enter ID and password to access the site.  on my local computer, I never see this popup login form. always automatically logged in.  What do I need to change on the server side to fix this issue.

in the IIS, I disabled anonymous authentication, only enabled windows authentication.  My computer and the serve are on the same domain.

Comment: You need to add the server to the local zone in internet explorer. The server needs to be added to the local intranet as it is not being automatically detected. Add the server to this list, restart IE and it will authenticate automatically.

Comment: I am glad mark it below as accepted answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the server to the local zone in internet explorer. The server needs to be added to the local intranet as it is not being automatically detected. Add the server to this list, restart IE and it will authenticate automatically.